# Uniqueness and Existence problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I just need a bit of help with this question.

If I know that $dg/dx = g^2$, and that $g(0) = g_0$, then I can solve:

$$
dg/dx = g^2\\
\frac{1}{g^2} dg = dx \\
-\frac{1}{g} = x + \hat c \\
-g = \frac {1}{x + \hat c} \\
g = \frac{1}{-x - \hat c}. \\
$$

Solving for the specific solution,
$$
g_0 = \frac{1}{0 - \hat c} \\
\hat c  = -\frac{1}{g_0}
$$

This means that
$g(x) = \frac {g_0}{1-g_0x}$.

My question is: **How do I determine the maximum interval on which the solution is defined?**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that there might not exist a **maximum** interval in which a solution is defined, in general you can only be sure about **maximal** intervals.

It's easy to check that the maximal intervals in which a solution to $g'=g^2$ is defined are $\left]-\infty, \dfrac{1}{g_0}\right[$ and $\left]\dfrac{1}{g_0}, +\infty\right[$, if $g_0\neq 0$.

Now regarding the I.V.P. $g'=g^2, g(0)=g_0$ you can indeed assure the existence of a maximum interval in which the solution is defined, because $0$ can only be in one of the above intervals. Do a discussion by cases:

1. If $g_0=0$, clearly $g=\bf 0$ and it is defined over $\Bbb R$.
2. If $g_0>0$, then $g(x)=g(x) = \dfrac {g_0}{1-g_0x},$ for all $x\in \left]-\infty, \dfrac{1}{g_0}\right[$ and this is a maximum interval of definition.
3. If $g_0<0$, then $g(x)=g(x)=g(x) = \dfrac {g_0}{1-g_0x}$, for all $x\in \left]\dfrac{1}{g_0}, +\infty\right[$ and this is a maximum interval of definition.

This takes care of existence.

To justify uniqueness for each of the cases note that the I.V.P. is $g'(x)=f(x,g(x)), g(0)=g_0$, where $f(a,b)=b^2$ for all $(a,b)\in \Bbb R^2$ and $f$ is  [locally Lipschitz continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuous#Definitions) and thus, by the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), there's uniqueness of solutions in each compact interval contained in one of the intervals above. Since this happens for **any** compact interval, it guarantees existence in the whole interval (one of the above).