# Find the largest $x$ interval containing $0$ on which $y$ is well-defined.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently taking an intro course on ordinary differential equations and was given this homework problem:

Find the solution of the following differential equation:$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2(1-2x)$$ $$y(0) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Find the largest $x$ interval containing $0$ on which $y$ is well defined. Sketch the graph of $y$ over that interval.

Finding the particular solution of the differential equation was easy enough, yielding $$y = \frac{1}{x^2-x-2}$$ but I don't know what's meant by "well defined". Could someone please elaborate as to what that means?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585398/uniqueness-and-existence-problem/585409#585409).

Answer (score 1):

Look for the intervals that the denominator is not zero.  For example,
$$
x(1-x) = 2
$$
yields values of $x$ where the denominator would be zero and thus the value of $y$ undefined.

Comment: So by "well defined" they basically mean to find an interval such that there are no discontinuities on that interval? That clears things up a bit. Thank you.

Comment: Well defined can mean different things in different contexts.  Such as, being continuous and smooth, thus differentiable.  But, here, by the nature of your answer to the problem, allowing the dividing by zero is definitely not well-defined.

Comment: Do you know of any good resources that go further into the subject matter? I'd like to read more about it.

Comment: Any good Calculus text should go into these issues.  If not, then I would declare it not to be a good text.  However, continuity, smoothness (e.g. differentiable) and other such matters are typically covered in Advanced Calculus or Real Analysis type texts.  The text I used in school (mid-60s) for Real Analysis is "Methods of Real Analysis" by Goldberg published in 1963.  My copy still has the original university bookstore price on the inside cover, $5.  Books were cheaper then.

Comment: Ok, I'll check out an advanced calc textbook. My current textbook is poorly written and does not cover such things, unfortunately.

Comment: I recommend getting an Analysis type text if you are a serious math student.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Fist of all, it seems that the solution is not correct. If, as you wrote, $$y = -\frac{1}{x(1+x)+2}$$ then $$lhs=\frac{2 x+1}{(x (x+1)+2)^2}$$ $$rhs=\frac{1-2 x}{(x (x+1)+2)^2}$$ which are not the same.

Fix your mistake, and take into account what previous answers suggested.

As said, the problem is with the denominator and $x (x+1)+2$ does not show any real root. This may not be the case for the correct solution of the differential equation.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thanks for that catch, When I solved it I mistakenly used $(1+2x)$ instead of $(1-2x)$ when writing the problem on paper!

Comment: This happens to everyone ! You could have suspected that the problem was too simple ! Cheers :-)