# Solutions of nonlinear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

1. Show that the differential equation $x^.=x^1/5$ with initial condition $x(0)=0$ has non unique solutions. Why does the theorem on uniqueness of solutions not apply?

$$x(t)=(\frac{4(t-t_0)}{5})^{5/4}$$

$=z(t;t_0)=0$ for $t\le\ t_0$
$=z(t;t_0)=(\frac{4(t-t_0)}{5})^{5/4}$ for $t\ge\ t_0$

The theorem on uniqueness of solutions does not apply because $f'(0)$ is not defined

2. Consider the differential equation $x^.=x^2$ (sorry I don't know how to format the x dot), with initial condition $x(0)=x_0≠0$.

a. Verify that the theorem on existence and uniqueness applies.

For this step, I am not really sure what to do? For a previous question there was an example that the theorem on existence and uniqueness fails because $f'(0)$ was undefined, so for this part I just wrote down:

$x^.=x^2$
$f(x)=x^2$
$f'(x)=2x$
$f'(0)=2(0)=0$

My book didn't really do a good job of explaining this theorem, so I am not really sure what the requirements are.

b. Solve for an explicit solution.
$$x^.=x^2$$
$$f(x)=x^2$$
$$F(x)=∫1/f(x)=∫dt$$
$$=∫1/x^2$=∫dt$$
$$=∫x^{-2}$=∫dt$$
$$=-x^-1=t-t_0$$
$$=x^-1=t_0+t$$
$$=x(t)=\frac{1}{t_0+t}$$

c. What is the maximal interval of definition if $x_0>0$?

Comment: You can find 2. solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585398/uniqueness-and-existence-problem/585409#585409).

Comment: $\LaTeX$ for $\dot x$ is "\dot x"; and don´t forget your dollar signs!  Cheers'